# Empty cases in Swift

Tags: swift

What is the difference between line A and line B:

```
let a = 1
switch a {
case 1:
    break;//line A
case 2:
    print("2")
default:
    ()//line B
}
```

My guess is that `break` is saying leave the `switch`, whereas `()` is saying do nothing.

I'm not sure what to search for this, and I'm new to Swift, so links are appreciated

Answer (score 3):

In your example, there is no difference. They are both placeholders. The rule is that a case cannot be completely empty. Both are acting as ways of meeting that requirement.

Comment: Do they compile down to the exact same thing?

Comment: @nhgrif taking a guess - in my example they might, but after some tests it appears you can have statements after `()` but not after `break` (so there are instances where they definitely wouldn't compile to the same thing)

Comment: To clarify, I'm not saying that syntactically or semantically `()` and `break` mean anything like the same thing. But they function the same way _in the example the OP gave_; they are just a way solving the problem that the case can't be empty.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: personally, I always write `break` if I need a switch case placeholder. I think the use of `()` looks silly. But it's legal! And see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_switch_statement